# How can I check the font of a expression generated by LaTex formula is embedded?

Tags: fonts, tex-core, embedding, inkscape

I'm using LaTex formula in inkscape. I drew a figure using LaTex formula and exported to PDF. Then, I opened the PDF and checked Files -> Property -> Font. However, nothing was written there.

How can I check the font of a expression generated by LaTex formula is embedded?

Comment: If the PDF file does not contain fonts, then inkscape has converted the glyph outlines to path drawing commands.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Specifically, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Both methods for including LaTeX formulas in Inkscape ([Extensions->Render->LaTeX](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX) or extension [textext](https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/)) are using [`pstoedit`](http://pstoedit.net/) to convert the LaTeX output to SVG. Therefore, I assume that the glyph outlines are extracted and converting them to vector path expressions instead of using characters from text fonts (Inkscape is a vector graphics program, not a text program). As result, the final PDF file will not contain any fonts.

(Disclaimer: I could not test properly, because the installed versions of `pstoedit` and `ghostscript` did not work together and failed.)

An alternative to embed LaTeX formulas with fonts is the following procedure:

- Creating a LaTeX file (e.g. with class `standalone`) and the formula.
- Conversion to PDF via LuaLaTeX, pdfLaTeX, ...
- Install the TeX fonts so that Inkscape knows them.
- Import the PDF file in Inkscape.
- When the figure is saved as PDF in Inkscape, use text output option "Embed fonts" and do not use "Convert text to paths".

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late.  Thank you for telling me that a eqation using LaTex formula is a vector diagram. I'm appreciated for your help!